# Difference between cardinality "*", and "0..*" - UML

Tags: uml, cardinality

What's the difference between the operator `*` and the operator `0..*` in UML (unified modeling language)?

I saw this two cardinality operators, but I don't now which one I must to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The notation '*' is a shortcut for '0..*'. the correct notation to use in this case is '*'.
From the UML 2.4 spec:

> A multiplicity with zero as the lower bound and an unspecified upper bound may use the alternative notation containing a single star “*” instead of “0..*.”